# Close all open Featherlight windows before opening a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

I'm registering multiple featherlight instances upon page-load

```
jQuery('.feedback').featherlight(jQuery( "#feedback-box" ), { closeIcon: 'close'});
jQuery('#imprint').featherlight(jQuery( "#imprint-box" ), { closeIcon: 'close'});
```

When one box is opened I would like to close all other open ones before.

How can I achieve this?

**Edit:** I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
$('.feedback').featherlight($( "#feedback-box" ), { 
    closeIcon: 'close', 
    beforeOpen: $.featherlight.close()
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `beforeOpen` to be a function...

With the code you gave, you will get an error in the console, won't you?

You need to write instead:

```
// ...
beforeOpen: function() { $.featherlight.close() }
```

Comment: It works, can you explain why the anonymous function is needed here?

Comment: Just saw this. I guess `beforeOpen: $.featherlight.close` should work. With your code it would execute the close function and assign the return value to beforeOpen. Without the braces it just assigns the close function to beforeOpen

Comment: Should work too, as long as `close` doesn't rely on `this` being `$.featherlight`, which you can't really assume.